# How can I optimize dijsktra path finding query for speed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

Through postgresql, postgis, pgrouting and nodejs I am working on a project which basically finds a path between shops.

**There are three tables in my database**

**1**.CREATE TABLE public."edges" (id int, name varchar(100), highway varchar(100), oneway varchar(100), surface varchar(100), the_geom geometry, source int, target int);

**2**.CREATE TABLE public."edges_noded" (id bigint, old_id int, sub_id int, source bigint, target bigint, the_geom geometry, name varchar(100), type varchar(100), distance double precision);

**3**.CREATE TABLE public."edges_noded_vertices_pgr" (id bigint, cnt int, chk int, ein int, eout int, the_geom geometry); –

And the query by which I am finding path

> **client.query( "WITH dijkstra AS (SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id,source,target,distance AS cost FROM
>   edges_noded',"+source+","+target+",FALSE)) SELECT seq, CASE WHEN
>   dijkstra.node = edges_noded.source THEN
>   ST_AsGeoJSON(edges_noded.the_geom) ELSE
>   ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Reverse(edges_noded.the_geom)) END AS
>   route_geom_x,CASE WHEN dijkstra.node = edges_noded.source THEN
>   ST_AsGeoJSON(edges_noded.the_geom) ELSE
>   ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Reverse(edges_noded.the_geom)) END AS route_geom_y
>   FROM dijkstra JOIN edges_noded ON(edge = id) ORDER BY
>   seq",(err,res)=>{ })**

This query works for me but taking too much time for example, If I want to find a path between 30 shops then it is taking almost 25 to 30 sec which is too much.

After searching about this problem I found this link
**https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16886/how-can-i-optimize-pgrouting-for-speed/16888**
In this link **Délawenis** is saying that **use a st_buffer so it doesn't get all ways, but just the "nearby" ways:**

So I tried to apply **st_buffer** in above query but not got any success.
If someone has any idea plz help me with this problem.

**If this approach is wrong please also tell me the right way.**

Comment: Can you post a `CREATE TABLE` statement and an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` from this query?

Comment: There are three tables in my database, 1.CREATE TABLE public."edges" (id int, name varchar(100), highway  varchar(100), oneway varchar(100), surface varchar(100), the_geom  geometry, source int, target int);  2.CREATE TABLE public."edges_noded" (id bigint, old_id int, sub_id int, source bigint, target bigint, the_geom geometry, name varchar(100), type varchar(100), distance double precision);                                            
 3.CREATE TABLE public."edges_noded_vertices_pgr" (id bigint, cnt int, chk int, ein int, eout int, the_geom geometry);

Comment: could you add it to your question? Normally people don't look for info in the comments :-D

Comment: does `CREATE INDEX idx_edges_noded_id ON edges (id);` help?